# Crystal Report fails to load on Windows 2003 os

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

Crystal Report 10 fails to load on Windows 2003 OS. We're developing with .net 3.5 with C#.net.

It works properly on dev box which contains similar configuration but without a McAFEE Anti-virus software on it.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Error Message:

```
[COMException (0x800002ad): Error in File UNKNOWN.RPT:
The request could not be submitted for background processing.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass
                            .Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper
                              .Open(Object& DocumentPath, Int32 Options) +95
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper
                                       .EnsureDocumentIsOpened() +271
```

Error in: `http://xxx/Reports/AgencyDetailReport.aspx`. Error Message:`Load report failed`.

```
TARGETSITE: Void EnsureDocumentIsOpened() STACKTRACE: at 
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper
   .EnsureDocumentIsOpened() at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.
      ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod,
Int16 parentJob) at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.
    Load(String filename) at Reports_AgencyDetailReport
          .CreateCrystalReportDocument(ReportObject rptObj) in
     c:\xxx\testapplication\Reports\AgencyDetailReport.aspx.cs:line 122
     at Reports_AgencyDetailReport.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
      in c:\xxx\testapplication\Reports\AgencyDetailReport.aspx.cs:line 99
```

Comment: Does it give any error messages at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a permission issue. I set 'NETWORK SERVICE' user the permission on my 'C:' drive which had the application as well as the required softwares.

On giving the permission, the Crystal reports started getting displayed.

Thanks for the responses. Specially to @Arvo

Comment: Nice suggestion friend, Its big help for me

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the stacktrace, it seems it is unable to find the file on the specified path OR the access to the file (or dir) could be a problem.

Comment: the same application runs on a pre-production environment. File paths are the same and mostly they are respective paths not absolute. Still, will check it out.

Comment: What about access rights? W2003 has pretty strict access policy; your aspx may run as very restircted user and have no rights to open file.
Have you tried switching McAffee off?

Comment: @Arvo you're right. it was a access right issue. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Installed CR for VS 2010 Runtime for 64 bits apps
Then, made a new integrated pool with administrator rights to pool.